# Should added duplicates be shown under the "Linked" section?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, linked-questions

I closed (dupe hammered) this question today:

- [nothing's wrong with my query still gives mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529073/nothings-wrong-with-my-query-still-gives-mysql-result-expects-parameter-1-to)

I'm curious to know why only **"[Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)"** shows up under the "Linked" section and not the 2 other duplicates that were added afterwards, being:

- [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)
- [What to replace mysql_result with for MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838901/what-to-replace-mysql-result-with-for-mysqli)

I tend to think that the other two would have shown up.

I've included a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Gosh darn it. I hard reloaded a few times before posting and just now... they appeared. Sorry for the question, my bad. I'll accept and +1. Thanks Paul.

Comment: What I find a bit odd though, is that I closed that question 33 mins ago (as per the time of this comment) and only a minute ago (of this posting), did the others show up under "Linked". That's why I posted the question and I did hard reload that question quite a few times.

Comment: One thing I did notice (in that question I closed) though is that, it seems that the ordering between the duplicates in the question and the "Linked" are different. The most upvoted appears in the "Linked" area as opposed to the original duplicate used. I take it that that is normal?